# Every 4th Monday?

Tags: ruby, date

I need a reminder every 4th Monday (= every **28 days**) from the Monday I start counting. So I thought I can have ruby script

- to send me an email ( I know how so do this part )
- **every 4th Monday** , not every 4th Monday of a month. ( **<---** how to code this bit in ruby? )

I will run the ruby scrip via **cron** every Monday ....

Comment: updated my question. I meant every 28 dyas...

Comment: Sounds nice.  Do you have a question?

Comment: @David: at least four people understood as you can see there are four answers. So the questions is the second bullet point.

Comment: wow, could you leave a comment why you voted down?

Comment: @Andrew: not sure what you meant by your comment. At the time David commented here there were already 4 answers here....

Comment: @Radek: 1) Are you not sure what I meant, or are you just not interested? 2) Victor wasn't sure whether you were asking about how to determine the date, or how to send an email.

Comment: Asking for an explanation of a downvote is perfectly reasonable, how else can one learn? The proper response would be guiding in the right direction. The problem was with the focus and clarity of the question, and did not warrant a mocking of his understanding of English.

Comment: @Joshua: Except that an explanation had already been provided. He chose to disregard it.

Comment: @Andrew: 1) I did not understand what you meant. If I wasn't interested I wouldn't ask. 2) Are you taking about Victor that answered my question? I cannot see the part where he wasn't sure ... I had these words `to send me an email ( I know how so do this part )` in the very first version of my question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already determined that it's a Monday, then count the days since the beginning of the year (`yday()`), modulus by 28, and see if the result is in 22 and 27 (inclusive) or is 0.

Given a starting (initial run) date, you can just use `step(28)` to get the next date and if it equals the current date, run and then store that for your next run.

As an aside, if you had meant the 4th Monday in the month, check the current day of the Month, and if it's between the 22nd and 28th of the month, you're in the fourth occurance of that day of the week that month.

Comment: are you sure I should count the days from the beginning of the year? As I want to get every 4th Monday from the Monday I start counting?

Comment: I store the initial day in the source code. Maybe I can 'just' count days from the initial date to 'today' and then use your modulus 28.

Comment: it's not that I am determined :-) I need to pay rent every 4th Monday. And Google Calendar is for every 4th Monday in a month. So today I realized I am late with my payment.

Comment: @Radek, you can have `step` return multiple dates by passing in a limit as well, and then just check if the current date is in the result.

Comment: oki doki. Let me check the doc for `step` command. Sounds like you game a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Give [this](https://github.com/javan/whenever) a try. Whenever is cron for ruby.

Answer (score 1):

This gentleman calculated the first week of the month, if you're running your script every Monday by cron, then you only need to find out if it is the 4th week of the month by ruby.

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95015

Comment: I need a reminder every 4th Monday = every 28 days (see my updated question) not every 4th Monday of a month.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use these two ruby gems:

To set a cron job -> WHENEVER - https://github.com/javan/whenever

```
gem install whenever
```

To send an email (obviously) -> GMAIL - https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail
    gem install gmail

Good Luck :D